# What is the probability of getting yahtzee?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting a [yahtzee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Lower_section) using $N$ dice with $X$ sides in $Y$ throws in a single round?

Which side of the dice appears on the yahtzee with doesn't matter (i.e. it doesn't matter if I throw ones, or twos, etc.). I also assume perfect strategy is used; that is, after each throw, one saves the number at which the most dice landed (in case of a tie, one just picks at random).

Comment: @runaros: Would you please explain the game, what does it mean "to get yahtzee"?

Comment: Throwing five or six dice and trying to get various combinations of those dice. Three throws every round (but some rule variations allow saving throws to later rounds), and you can choose how many dice to rethrow between throws.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee

Comment: @runaros: I was hoping you would edit the question itself. Only you and our moderators (and high-rep users) have that option.

Comment: you start by rolling N dice, you get Y rolls, on every roll but the first you can choose to save the results of some of the dice and only roll the rest of them. A yahtzee is when at the aftermath of a roll, all dice (those rolled and those saved from previous rolls) show the same number.

Comment: @runaros do you mean in a single round(with rerolls allowed in a round) or over the course of the entire game? In the second case we need to talk about strategy. :/

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I thought the game was so common that "everybody" knows about it. I guess that is not the case. I've included a link in the question.

@yohay: Good explanation.

@BBischof: I meant in a single round, with the possibility of using saved rerolls from previous rounds (hence the Y part of the question rather than the standard 3). Edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What follows is a solution to a smaller problem; I don't have a good way to determine the probabilities of exactly k of some kind being the most of any kind on the first roll, but the work below could be used from that point to get an answer.

Let $f(N,X,Y)$ be the probability of getting all 1s with N dice, each with X sides, in at most Y rolls, where after each roll, 1s are retained and only non-1 dice are re-rolled.  Working 1 roll at a time, the first roll could have exactly $k=0,\dots,N$ 1s.  The probability of exactly k 1s in a single roll is ${N\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)^k\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{N-k}$ and having k 1s in the first roll, we then need $N-k$ 1s in the remaining $Y-1$ rolls.  So, 
$$f(N,X,Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}{N\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)^k\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{N-k}f(N-k,X,Y-1).$$
Also, the probability of all 1s on 0 dice is 1 (0 of the 0 dice are guaranteed to be 1), so $f(0,X,Y)=1$, and the probability of all 1s on $N\ge 0$ dice in 0 rolls is 0 (can't get any 1s without rolling some dice), so $f(N,X,0)=0$ for $N\ge 0$.  This is a complete definition of $f(N,X,Y)$, though it does not lend itself to easy computation.  (However, software like Mathematica may be able to compute from this definition.  In Mathematica: `f[n_, x_, y_] := If[n == 0, 1, If[y == 0, 0, 
       Sum[
    Binomial[n, k]*(1/x)^k*(1 - 1/x)^(n - k)*f[n - k, x, y - 1], 
         {k, 0, n}]]]`.)

Comment: Nice answer. I'll upvote it once I get enough rep, and probably accept it after some time as well :)

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Probabilities) "the probability
of a Yahtzee for any three-roll turn is about 0.04603 (or $\frac{347897}{7558272}$), or roughly 1 in 22 attempts."

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer to your question, but at least it is a closed form. For 5 normal (6-sided), dice, the exact probability of achieving a yahtzee, following the optimum strategy, given $n$ rolls is

$1+\frac{53}{13} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2n+1}+\frac{11 \cdot 5^n}{13 \cdot 2^{n+5} \cdot 3^{3n+1}}  -\frac{5^n}{8 \cdot 3^{2n-2}}  -\frac{7 \cdot 5^{n+1}}{ 2^{n+5} 3^{n-1}} $

For example, setting $n=3$ gives $\frac{347897}{7558272}$.

Comment: I have no ideas where those numbers are coming from.
The result is in general agreement, meaning approximately the same as other answers, but can anyone explain this.  It appears to be a totally different approach than my approach.

Comment: @nickalh, why ? It gives the  answer for any !

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not able to give you an analytical answer, but this question just screamed to be programmed. Now I am sorry that I haven't used Matlab ( which would be much less code ) but I implemented it in c++. The code is simply your rules implemented in **my not so good** c++. I used g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. If you run the code, it will print the results and also write the pairs (number of dices | avg. number of throws) in out.txt. The result is plotted attached, plotted with gnuplot for number of dices $\leq$ 40.

[See the results here](http://s10.postimage.org/i0fli3695/results.png) as I dont know much about gnuplot and couldn't upload a .ps to MathSE I had to upload it there. For every number of dices, 10000 experiments have been player.
The code is probably terrible slow so everyone feel free to improve it ;)

[This here](http://postimage.org/image/fy1qihn0h/)  does the same computation for number of dices $\leq 400$ but only 1000 experiments each.

Maybe you can use this to varify any of the formulas.

**yahtzee.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int hasYourNumber(vector<int>,int );
int sum(int* ,int );
int mostFrequent ( vector<int> );
vector<int>throwDice(int);
int role();
void playYahtzee(int,int,bool);

int main ( void ) {

    int REP = 10000; // Number of repeting the experiment
    bool echo = 0;    // print information (yes 1,no 0)
    for (int numberOfDices=1;numberOfDices<40;numberOfDices++){
        playYahtzee(numberOfDices,REP,echo);
    }


    return 0;
}


void playYahtzee(int N,int REP,bool echo){// N dices with 6 faces each;


    srand( time(NULL) );        // initialize random generator  
    int* throws = new int[REP]; // save number of throws for each experiment
    vector <int> dices;     // save dices that came up in one throw inside this, vector just for size(), my way...

    for (int k = 0;k<REP;k++){
        bool first = true;      // is it the first throw?
        int AmountOfYourNumber = 0;     // how often as our number occured
        int yourNumber = -1;        // whats your number
        int numberOfThrows = 0;     // how often have we been throwing in this round
        while (AmountOfYourNumber<N){   // finish if our number has occured N times
            numberOfThrows++;
            dices.clear();
            dices = throwDice(N-AmountOfYourNumber); // place random integers between 1 and 6 inside
            if (first){
                yourNumber = mostFrequent(dices);// choose the most frequent number
                AmountOfYourNumber += hasYourNumber(dices,yourNumber); // how often has it your number
                first = false;
            }else{
                AmountOfYourNumber += hasYourNumber(dices,yourNumber);
            }
            if (echo){ // some output mostly for debugging
                printf("Your number is %d and it has occured %d times in throw 1 to %d.\n", 
                        yourNumber, AmountOfYourNumber,numberOfThrows);
                printf("\tNumbers in this throw:\n\t");
                for (int i=0;i<dices.size();i++) printf("%d\t",dices[i]);
                printf("\n \n");
            }
        }

        throws[k] = numberOfThrows; // save number of throws
    }   

    double avg = double(sum(throws,REP))/double(REP);   // calculate average
    printf("Average number (over %d repetitions) of attempts, when playing with %d dices equals  %g\n",REP,N,avg);
    ofstream output;
    output.open ("out.txt",fstream::app);
    output << N << " " << avg<< endl;
    output.close();
}
int sum(int* throws,int N){ // = sum_i throws[i]
    int s = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) s+= throws[i];
    return s;
}
int hasYourNumber(vector<int> dices,int yourNumber){ // calculates how often yournumber is in dices
    int N = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<dices.size();i++){
        if ( dices[i] == yourNumber) N++;
    }
    return N;
}

int mostFrequent ( vector<int> dices){ // which is the most frequent number, takes first best
    int freq [6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int i=0;i<dices.size();i++){
        freq[dices[i]-1]++;
    }
    int yourNumber = -1;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
        if (freq[i]>max) {yourNumber = i+1 ; max = freq[i];}
    }
    return yourNumber;
}

vector <int> throwDice(int M){ // throws M dices
    vector <int> dices;
    for (int i=0;i<M;i++) dices.push_back(role());
    return dices;
}
int role(){ // throws one dice
    return rand() % 6 +1;
}
```